# Freeing memory used by database operations

Tags: c#, database

I am writing a C# database program that reads data from one database, does calculations on the data, then writes the results to another database.  This involves a large volume of data requiring repeated cycles of reads from the source database then writes to the destination database.

I am having problems with having my memory eaten up.  I use `dispose` and `clear` functions when I can, but my research indicates that these don't really free memory of data tables and data connections.

One suggestion I found was to put the database calls within `using` structures.  But for me this would mean opening and closing both data connections many times during a run. This seems rather inelegant and way to make the program run slower.  Also, the program may evolve to the point where I will also need to write data back to the source database.

The most straight forward way to structure my workflow is to keep both database connections open all the time.  But this seems to be part of my problem.

Does anyone have suggestions at to program structure to help with memory usage?

Comment: Unless you have global objects with undetermined life time, you do not use `Dispose` or `Close`, you only use `using`. If you want to keep your connections opened, do so, but use `using` for any object other than connections.

Comment: What kind of database setup are you working with? Are both databases of the same DBMS (i.e. Oracle and Oracle, or is it SQL-Server and Oracle or mysql and postgresql, etc...)? Are both databases co-located or owned by the same person/company? Is this something that you could do with a DBLink and sql stored procedures?

Comment: If you don't get memory pressure, GC will not run and clean up the resources. Try forcing a `GC.Collect()` and see if that helps, but don't use it if you don't have to, this sounds like memory management doing its job, if you have too many GC's, the performance will drop.

Comment: unless youre running in memory out of exception just leave it as it is, GC will take care of it, or well, you can try to force it as mentioned by Ron. Just make sure you dont keep references to the objects you dont use anymore, like some global cache, table etc Also if you use some shitty ORM or data connection driver it might have memory leak underneath or it might be using CACHE that you dont know about...

Comment: Right now I am going from SQL Server to SQL Server.  But the customers who use this may have Oracle in the mix on one end or the other.

Comment: The program runs well until it clogs itself up.  No memory exceptions, but the processing just slows down to a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this problem down a little.

Memory is being used to hold the data you retrieve from the database.
Clearing this **data** will fix your memory usage problem.

So the question is, how is your data stored?
Is it a list of objects? Is it in a dataset? Is it in some sort of ORM model?
If you can clear/flush/null/dispose of the DATA you should be good to go.

Instantiating connection object inside a "using" statement only makes sure the connection object is disposed of, it doesn't explicitly clear any data you retrieved. (ORMs may dispose of the data inside of them, but not any copies you made calling .ToList() for example.)

External resources like databases, filesystem etc, it is always best to leverage a lock late release early policy and that is why you are probably getting feedback to open/close your connections as needed. But this won't help your memory issue. And it is completely fine to keep a database connection open for multiple commands.

Comment: *"Clearing this data will fix your memory usage problem"* It won't unless there is memory pressure, its still allocated, but GC won't free the resources until it has to.

Comment: Agreed. I guess my point was to make sure that the data is cleared allowing GC to do its thing. I didn't mean to infer that clearing the data instantly clears the memory.

Comment: Let me see if I can answer some of your questions.  I am reading the data into DataTables.  I am trying to Clear the DataTables at the earliest opportunity as the data gets moved downstream, but this does not seem to help.  Some of the data gets spun off into arrays of doubles.  I would think the arrays going out of scope would free the memory used by these.

Comment: I am using a single class to do the heavy lifting of data manipulation.  There are several logic steps I have to take in processing the data.  Each step has its own function.  The data connections and DataTables are declared as class level variables, so all the functions can share them.  Is there an issue here regarding if the variables should be declared (such as being defined as static)?

Comment: Should the variables be "newed" in the declaration or should this wait until they are actually used?  Some of the data gets spun off into arrays of doubles.  I would think the arrays going out of scope would free the memory used by these.